# c# backgroundworker reportProgress return percentage and Struct

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

my backgroundworker should return the percentage and also an object.
Its a struct.

```
serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); // clear InBuffer
serialPort.Write(adv_request, 0, 3); // Write byte array to serial port, with no offset, all 3 bytes
process_DoWork(serialPort);
worker.ReportProgress(0, pfc_parsedData); //return parsed data to main thread
```

Here I get an exception "System.InvalidCastException"

```
public void request_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) //this function is need update mainthread controls
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
    {
         sbStatus.Text = "Logging active...";
         Pfc_parsedData pfc_parsedData = (Pfc_parsedData)sender;
    }
    else
    {
         sbStatus.Text = "Offline";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` is the background worker, not the data that you provided when reporting progress.  That data is in `e.UserState`.

Comment: I tried this, but this throws also an exception:                 `Pfc_parsedData pfc_parsedData = new Pfc_parsedData();

                pfc_parsedData = (Pfc_parsedData)e.UserState;`    System.NullReferenceException

Comment: @BastiAn Then you'll need to figure out what is null that you're trying to dereference and either figure out why it's null when you think it isn't, or you'll need to not dereference it when its null.

Comment: @BastiAn You don't need to create a new instance of `Pfc_ParsedData`.  `Pfc_parsedData pfc_parsedData = (Pfc_parsedData)e.UserState;` should work.